# How to Retrieve the value from Datetime-local input?

Tags: php, html

I am currently experimenting with PHP. I am creating a simple form that requests a user to input their, name, telephone, and appointment time. Once the user inputs all these values, I want to create a calendar event based on these data. (a calendar event in apple ical or google calendar)

I decided to use a third party framework, AddEvent, to help me create an .ical file so that I can add it to icalendar or google calendar. However, I ran into an issue.

I used the datetime-local input type to gather the appointment time issue. But when I do that, and try to echo it out, it always prints it out in a specific format like this (2016-06-30T02:02).

I want to know how I can alter the format so it is like this (07/13/2016 16:00).

Thanks,

Comment: can you show us what you have done ?

Comment: Yes.This is what I have done so far. 'Arrival Time: <input type="datetime-local" name="arrivalTime">' I did this to gather the appointment time. Then i tried to create a function like this function 'dateToCal($timestamp){
   return date("d/m/y",$timestamp);
  } ' and tried echoing my arrivalTime like this 'echo dateToCal($arrivalTime);'. However that did not work. The dateToCal echoed dates in the right format, but not the date i inputted. Sorry, I am new to this so i don't know what is a better way to show you what I have done.

Comment: i meant the coding you have done !

Comment: estions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, how do you suggest I improve my question then? I felt my problem was that i was unable to alter the format of the datetime-local input value introduced my HTML5. How else should I ask this question to make it even clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M', strtotime($datetime_local_input));
```

Comment: You'are welcome. Could you please select this answer as the right one :D !